# get index of item on 2d grid given (x,y) location

Tags: grid, indexing, location, position

How can you get the index (counting from top-left) of an item on a grid given the (x,y) location?

Answer (score 3):

```
NUM_COLS*x + y;
```

Where NUM_COLS is the number of columns in the grid.

Comment: x is usually horizontal position, y is usually vertical position. For every vertical we skip the full width of the horizontal. Formula would be width*y+x.